# Efficient merging (removing duplicates) of arrays

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, aggregate, array

I have two tables, `left2` and `right2`. Both tables will be large (1-10M rows).

```
CREATE TABLE left2(id INTEGER, t1 INTEGER, d INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE left2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id,t1);

CREATE TABLE right2( t1 INTEGER, d INTEGER, arr INTEGER[] );
ALTER TABLE right2 ADD PRIMARY KEY(t1,d);
```

I will perform this type of query:

```
SELECT l.d + r.d,
       UNIQ(SORT((array_agg_mult(r.arr)))
FROM left2 l,
     right2 r
WHERE l.t1 = r.t1
GROUP BY l.d + r.d
ORDER BY l.d + r.d;
```

Where for aggregation of arrays I use the function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult(anyarray) (
SFUNC=array_cat,
STYPE=anyarray,
INITCOND='{}');
```

After concatenating the arrays, I use the `UNIQ` function of the `intarray` module. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Is there any index on the `arr` field to speed up the merging (with removing duplicates)? Can the aggregate function remove duplicates directly? Original arrays may be considered sorted (and they are unique) if that helps.

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2f8c70/2/0):

Comment: Are you going to query millions of rows at once? What are you doing with the result? Or will there be predicates to select a few? Can `right2.arr ` be NULL like your demo schema suggests? Do you need sorted arrays as result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Correct results?

First off: correctness. You want to produce an array of unique elements? Your current query does not do that. The function `uniq()` from the [**intarray** module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) only promises to:

> remove adjacent duplicates

Like [instructed in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#INTARRAY-FUNC-TABLE), you would need:

```
SELECT l.d + r.d, uniq(sort(array_agg_mult(r.arr)))
FROM   ...
```

Also gives you *sorted* arrays - assuming you want that, you did not clarify.

I see you [*have* `sort()` in your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2f8c70/2/0), so this may just be a typo in your question.

#### Postgres 9.5 or later

Either way,since Postgres 9.5 `array_agg()` has the capabilities of my `array_agg_mult()` built-in out of the box, and much faster, too:

- [Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763245/939860)
- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414884/939860)

There have also been other performance improvements for array handling.

#### Query

The main purpose of `array_agg_mult()` is to aggregate multi-dimensional arrays, but you only produce 1-dimensional arrays anyway. So I would at least try this alternative query:

```
SELECT l.d + r.d AS d_sum, array_agg(DISTINCT elem) AS result_arr
FROM   left2  l
JOIN   right2 r USING (t1)
     , unnest(r.arr) elem
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Which also addresses your question:

> Can the aggregate function remove duplicates directly?

Yes, it can, with `DISTINCT`. But that's not faster than `uniq()` for integer arrays, which has been optimized for integer arrays, while `DISTINCT` is generic for all qualifying data types.

Doesn't require the `intarray` module. **However**, the result is not necessarily sorted. Postgres uses varying algorithms for `DISTINCT`. Big sets are typically hashed, which leaves the result unsorted unless you add explicit `ORDER BY`. If you need sorted arrays, you *could* add `ORDER BY` to the aggregate function directly:

```
array_agg(DISTINCT elem ORDER BY elem)
```

But that's typically *slower* than feeding pre-sorted data to `array_agg()` (one big sort versus many small sorts). So I would sort in a subquery and *then* aggregate:

```
SELECT d_sum, uniq(array_agg(elem)) AS result_arr
FROM  (
   SELECT l.d + r.d AS d_sum, elem
   FROM   left2  l
   JOIN   right2 r USING (t1)
        , unnest(r.arr) elem
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This was the fastest variant in my cursory test on Postgres 9.4.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ed90a/1) based on the one you provided.

#### Index

I don't see much potential for any index here. The only option would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON right2 (t1, arr);
```

Only makes sense if you get index-only scans out of this - which will happen if the underlying table `right2` is substantially wider than just these two columns and your setup qualifies for [index-only scans. Details in the Postgres Wiki.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans)

Comment: Thanks +1. I will have to UNNEST later anyway, but want to check if removing duplicates in the arrays and then UNNEST is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really disappointed, this is an easy thing to do in Microsoft Access.  You can create a "remove duplicates" query then look at the SQL to see how it's doing it.  I'll have to fire up a Windows machine to look.  They vary, the query wizard does it.

One thing that works I think is to load all your data into one table then do SELECT DISTINCT into a new table.  You can also stick in an order by clause while you're at it.  I did it somehow a year ago, that must be it.

I'm combining 2 years worth of temperature data, the sensor sends 2 copies of the same data point every minute as a redundant safeguard.  Sometimes one gets trashed, but I only want to keep one.  I also have overlaps between files.

If the data is exactly the same format over the whole run, on a unix machine you can do something like

```
cat *.tab > points.txt
sort -n < points.txt > sorted.txt
uniq -u sorted.txt unique.txt
```

But uniq compares lines as strings and for example 18.7000 isn't the same as 18.7.  I've changed my software during the 2 years so I have both formats.

Comment: Disappointed from Postgres? Does Access even have arrays?

Comment: I don't know but it can remove duplicates, it's a common enough problem in data cleansing.  Select distinct is close enough.  You don't always have control over your raw data from  the real world.