# Wordcount in a field (all and unique) - is there a more elegant/optimal way?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, string-manipulation

Answering this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239873/how-to-find-the-count-of-words-all-and-unique-in-a-column-row-wise),

Given this table (constructed from the question):

```
CREATE TABLE wordcount (id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO wordcount (description) VALUES ('What a great day');
INSERT INTO wordcount (description) VALUES ('This is a product. It is useful');
```

produce this result:

```
     id  | word_count | unique_word_count |  Description                        
---------+------------+-------------------+---------------
     1   |  4         | 4                 | What a great day
     2   |  7         | 6                 | This is a product. It is useful
```

I gave the (correct) answer, which you can find [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239878/34007).

However in a comment, the OP then asked a further question - what if the string in question was  `['a', ' ', ' ', 'b']` and my solution broke down completely - for starters, the string wouldn't even `INSERT` into the table.

So, the question now is, how does one deal with strings like this - i.e. with apostrophes, square brackets &c. I'm going to give my own answer and also offer a bonus for a more elegant solution.

Solutions with multiple options will be highly prized as will those which show evidence of "thinking outside the box" (sorry for the cliché - but it fits here! :-) ). I'm also going to give a detailed explanation of my reasoning - that will earn kudos also! Options which mention other servers will also gain merit. Obviously, I can only award the bonus to one person, but I will upvote all decent answers.

I can only offer a bonus in two days - so I'll post my answer and will offer the bonus (+100) when I'm allowed to. Also, any solutions which deal with strings which my own can't deal with - haven't exhaustively tested yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to your solution: smart and with a solid explanation. But what about these cases: `''`, `NULL`, `'"§$%'`, `'-'`? No words. The count should be `0` - but your solution drops these rows altogether.

Also, any solution first and foremost **depends on the exact definition of "word"**, which can vary wildly ...

### Regular expression based string processing

Similar to your solution, with some alternative suggestions:

```
SELECT id
     , COALESCE(cardinality(arr), 0) AS word_count
     , unique_word_count
     , description
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , string_to_array(trim(regexp_replace(description, '\W+', ' ', 'g')), ' ') AS arr
   FROM   wordcount
   ) a
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT elem) AS unique_word_count
   FROM   unnest(arr) elem
   ) b ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b8655fa1821da5029bd7a55264e0fa0)* (extended test case)

The core is `regexp_replace(description, '\W+', ' ', 'g')` to replace all substrings of non-word characters with a single space. See [Regular Expression Class-shorthand Escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE). This removes all noise early in the game.

Followed up by cheap `trim()` to remove leading/trailing spaces, and `string_to_array()` to convert the prepared string to an array.

Get `word_count` from the array directly. Again: cheap.

The `unique_word_count` from a `LATERAL` subquery with `count(DISTINCT ...)`. That part may or may not be slower than a total unnest / aggregate. It's a bit simpler.

The `COALESCE` in the outer `SELECT` takes care of `NULL` input (the original question did not mention a `NOT NULL` constraint). Optional, in case you need `0` instead of `NULL`.

Or (faster in a quick test with short strings):

```
SELECT id
     , count(*) AS word_count
     , count(DISTINCT elem) AS unique_word_count
     , description
FROM  (
   SELECT id, description
        , unnest(string_to_array(trim(regexp_replace(description, '\W+', ' ', 'g')), ' ')) AS elem
   FROM   wordcount
   ) sub
GROUP  BY id, description;
```

This **drops** rows with 0 words like your answer does.

### (Ab-)using text search parser

Using the text search function [`ts_parse()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-DEBUG-TABLE) is simpler. May or may not be faster. But first study the various tokens identified by the the text search parser and see what matches your definition of "word":

```
SELECT * FROM ts_token_type('default')
```

For **only "ASCII Words"**:
(Unlike above, the underscore (`_`) is not treated as word character here):

```
SELECT w.id
     , count(*) AS word_count
     , count(DISTINCT token) AS unique_word_count
     , w.description
FROM   wordcount w, ts_parse('default', w.description) t
WHERE  t.tokid = 1 -- 'asciiword'
GROUP  BY w.id;
```

To keep `_` from separating  words, use simple `replace()` first:

```
SELECT w.id
     , count(*) AS word_count
     , count(DISTINCT token) AS unique_word_count
     , w.description
FROM   wordcount w, ts_parse('default', replace(w.description, '_', 'x')) t
WHERE  t.tokid = 1 -- 'asciiword'
GROUP  BY w.id;
```

Again, to keep all rows:

```
SELECT w.id
     , count(token) AS word_count
     , count(DISTINCT token) AS unique_word_count
     , w.description
FROM   wordcount w
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT t.token
   FROM   ts_parse('default', w.description) t
   WHERE  t.tokid = 1 -- 'asciiword'
   ) t ON true
GROUP  BY w.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c8f0315e58123dab1d2dd604660fb451)*

Related:

- [Efficient merging (removing duplicates) of arrays](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117913/efficient-merging-removing-duplicates-of-arrays/117941#117941)
- [How do I select arrays that are not empty?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186715/how-do-i-select-arrays-that-are-not-empty/186727)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Comment: Hi Erwin, and thanks for your usual high standard of reply! However, I played around with your solution and am puzzled by one thing - if I use the string 'under_score under-score', I get a word count of 3 and a unique word count of 3 - 2 and 2 I could understand. Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ded9685e96357fe3ae2cbd5965d10a48).

Comment: For the regular expression, an underscore (`_`)  is a word character, but the dash (`-`) is not. So you get `under_score` ,`under` and  `score` - 3 "words".
I also clarified `ts_parse()`which knows various kinds of "words". I added some more above to clarify.

Comment: Phew... got there just in time. Almost wished you hadn't posted such a beauty of an answer - migt've more answers that way?

Comment: Thanks for the praise. Re "got there just in time": Not sure I understand?

Comment: I upvoted just minutes before the bonus deadline **expired** hence the **phew**! However, I forgot to mark your answer as correct before the deadline expiry. Therefore, I owe you 100 points :-(.  I'll dig out a few old anwers of yours and upvote them instead :-) - but not so much as to make the cheat-suspicious! ;-)

Comment: Oh, nice little confusion. :) Never mind that. Only upvote what deserves it.

Answer (score 4):

First step obviously is to create the table and data (as per the question [mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239873/how-to-find-the-count-of-words-all-and-unique-in-a-column-row-wise)):

```
CREATE TABLE wordcount (id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO wordcount (description) VALUES ($$What a great day$$);
INSERT INTO wordcount (description) VALUES ($$This is a product. It is useful$$);
INSERT INTO wordcount (description) VALUES ($$['a', ' ', ' ', 'b']$$);
```

The first "lifesaver" was the dollar quoting (`$$`) - a really neat
PostgreSQL feature. I was really floundering before I came across
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758617/470530) - couldn't even get the data into the table (trying
backslashes, double quotes &c.)

My final SQL looks like this (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9fa9350aabb15d253ea003d14ebbfb3d)):

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT id,
    UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(description, ','), '[^\w\s]', '', 'g'), ' ')) as "word",
    description
  FROM wordcount
)
SELECT id,
       COUNT(word),
       COUNT(DISTINCT(word)),
       description
FROM cte1
WHERE LENGTH(word) > 0
GROUP BY id, description
ORDER BY id;
```

Result:

```
id  Word_count  Distinct_count  description
 1           4               4    What a great day
 2           7               6    This is a product. It is useful
 3           2               2    ['a', ' ', ' ', 'b']
```

## Logic explained:

I decided not to bother with capitalisation - i.e. "It" and "it" are different words in this case - if this is an issue, the simple addition of an `UPPER()` function would solve that - it's not core to the question.

Step 1:

```
SELECT id, REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(description, ',') FROM wordcount;
-- Keeping the id field helps clarity, even if superfluous.
```

Result:

```
id  regexp_split_to_table
1   What a great day
2   This is a product. It is useful
3   ['a'
3    ' '
3    ' '
3    'b']
```

Step 2 (remove all non-space, non-alpha)

```
SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(description, ','), '[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', 'g')
FROM wordcount;

-- Remove all non-alpha, non-spaces. Otherwise the words "product" and "product." would
-- be counted as different! Again, keeping the id field makes things clearer, 
-- even if not strictly necessary for purists
```

Result:

```
id  regexp_replace
1   What a great day
2   This is a product It is useful
3   a
3     
3     
3    b
```

Step 3 (put the strings into an array):

```
SELECT id, STRING_TO_ARRAY(REGEXP_REPLACE(
          REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(description, ','), '[^\w\s]', '', 'g'), ' ')
FROM wordcount;  
--              id again - not strictly necessary at this step.
```

Result:

```
id  string_to_array
1   {What,a,great,day}
2   {This,is,a,product,It,is,useful}
3   {a}
3   {"","",""}
3   {"","",""}
3   {"",b}
```

Finally, the answer itself - `UNNEST` and then select those words `LENGTH > 0` grouping by id and description.

i.e. `SELECT` the necessary from the following cte (Common Table Expression) - the cte isn't strictly necessary - I **could** have used the `UNNEST...` throughout my final query, but that would have been horrible to read and debug. It's the reason Common Table Expressions were invented!

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT id, 
    UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(description, ','), '[^\w\s]', '', 'g'), ' ')) as "word",
    description
  FROM wordcount
)
SELECT blah... (see above)
```

Comment: jsute an simple addition: with Postgres 12, you'll have generated columns that will allow to store that information. (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/ddl-generated-columns.html)

Comment: @Arkhena - thanks for that, but see my first comment [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239873/how-to-find-the-count-of-words-all-and-unique-in-a-column-row-wise) - great minds thinking alike! :-)